# Firebase get data in a webpage

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have firebase DB like this below:

[image: This is my FireBase DB]

and I am displaying the data in a table like this:

[image: HTML Output]

I have also uploaded my code to [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pran/oxr74s1r/6/).

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("tree1");
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  var data = snapshot.val().tree2.tree3;  
  for(var k in data){
    $("#gText").append("<th style='border:1px solid black'>"+k+"</th>");
    $("#vText").append("<td style='border:1px solid black'>"+data.k+"</td>"); //Error Here
  }
  $("#dummy").append("<td style='border:1px solid black'>"+data.name1+"</td>");
  $("#dummy").append("<td style='border:1px solid black'>"+data.name2+"</td>");
});
```

In the 2nd row of html output, I am getting "undefined", but in the 3rd row it's working fine. Why am I getting "undefined" in the 2nd row?

Comment: same the value of 3rd row. 3rd row values are put in a manual way. suppose i have 100 entries in TREE2 then it will be very difficult to type that much of codes. that is why i am asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
$("#vText").append("<td style='border:1px solid black'>"+data.k+"</td>");
```

into this:

```
$("#vText").append("<td style='border:1px solid black'>"+data[k]+"</td>");
```

Using bracket notation, you will be able to access the values of the properties.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oxr74s1r/14/)

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried many things but not that brackets. Thanks a lot.